# Avoid redirecting in a post action PHP

Tags: php, html, post, submit, action

So I have this form and when I click on the submit input, I get redirected to the action url. How can I avoid this and stay in the same url?

```
 ...
<form method="post" action="cart.php?action=add&pid='.$row["id"].'">
  <div class="cart-action" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary js-btn-minus" type="button">−</button>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="product-quantity form-control text-center"  name="quantity" value="1" size="2" placeholder="">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary js-btn-plus" type="button">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Agregar al carro" class="btnAddAction btn btn-outline-secondary" style="width: 100%;">
  </div>
</form>
...
```

And this is the code for adding a product to the cart

```
    //code for Cart
if(!empty($_GET["action"])) {
switch($_GET["action"]) {
    //code for adding product in cart
    case "add":
        if(!empty($_POST["quantity"])) {
            $pid=$_GET["pid"];
            $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE id='$pid'");
              while($productByCode=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $itemArray = array($productByCode["code"]=>array('name'=>$productByCode["name"], 'code'=>$productByCode["code"], 'quantity'=>$_POST["quantity"], 'price'=>$productByCode["price"], 'image'=>$productByCode["image"]));
            if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                if(in_array($productByCode["code"],array_keys($_SESSION["cart_item"]))) {
                    foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                            if($productByCode["code"] == $k) {
                                if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"])) {
                                    $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = 0;
                                }
                                $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] += $_POST["quantity"];
                            }
                    }
                } else {
                    $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
                }
            }  else {
                $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
            }
        }
    }
    break;

}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You must use ajax.

Comment: As @SimoneRossaini said, you should use asynchronous requests. You can use AJAX for it. Anyway, your PHP code contains some code smells that should definitely be fixed: Use prepared statements and definitely escape your input before using it somewhere else to prevent, for example, SQL injection attacks.

Comment: if the cart logic is already finished, just use a `header` redirect back to the page where you need to be. just add the message and tell the user, the item has been added

Answer (score 0):

You should use ajax

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
    });
});
```

Comment: doesn't necessarily mean OP should use ajax outright, once the cart logic is done, just redirect back to the product page (or the previous page), save sessions (flash sessions and whatnot) and tell that it's been added

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect user back to the previous URL using [headers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

```
header("Location: previous_page.php");
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a few ways to do this. This is one:

**Step 1:** Add a hidden input that includes the current page URL

```
<?php
   $url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
?>

<input type="hidden" name="url" value=<?=$url;?>"
```

**Step 2:** Then in your cart.php page, you need to add a redirect once you have added the product e.g.

```
if(!empty($_GET["action"])) {
switch($_GET["action"]) {
    //code for adding product in cart
    case "add":
        if(!empty($_POST["quantity"])) {
            $pid=$_GET["pid"];
            $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE id='$pid'");
              while($productByCode=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $itemArray = array($productByCode["code"]=>array('name'=>$productByCode["name"], 'code'=>$productByCode["code"], 'quantity'=>$_POST["quantity"], 'price'=>$productByCode["price"], 'image'=>$productByCode["image"]));
            if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                if(in_array($productByCode["code"],array_keys($_SESSION["cart_item"]))) {
                    foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                            if($productByCode["code"] == $k) {
                                if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"])) {
                                    $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = 0;
                                }
                                $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] += $_POST["quantity"];
                            }
                    }
                } else {
                    $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
                }
            }  else {
                $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
            }
        }
    }
    header("Location: ".$_POST['url']);
    break;

}
}
```

Comment: That's not very safe.

Comment: What unsafe about it? Genuinely asking

Comment: That URL can be hijacked and user can be redirected to the another domain. Redirections should be made from closed set.